# Parsing Date/Time strings in Java

Tags: java, date

When the following code executes, I get a *ParseException* error:

```
String date;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the date of birth, in format 'January 2, 2010'");
date = in.nextLine();
in.close();
Date birth = new Date();
birth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date);
birthcal.setTime(birth);
```

I think I understand why, as I haven't sanitized the input. I was wondering what the best way to solve this problem is. Any help in parsing dates would be appreciated.

(P.S. Another peculiar issue pops up when I try to catch the error, i.e.:

```
String date;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the date of birth, in format 'January 2, 2010'");
date = in.nextLine();
in.close();
Date birth = new Date();
try {
    birth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
birthcal.setTime(birth);
```

The issue here is a *NullPointerException*. I don't see how this can be. I thought when you initialized with `new Date()`, it set a value for it, meaning that the last line of the code will be at least pointing to SOMETHING. Any help on this would also be appreciated.)

Comment: Try to avoid asking multiple questions at once; it makes giving clear answers difficult. For your first issue, print out the `date` variable (or better yet, debug and inspect it) to make sure it's what you expect. For the second, always include a stack trace for exceptions; we need to know what line the exception is thrown from. Most likely, the problem is with an uninitialized `birthcal`, not `birth`.

Comment: can you try "MM dd, yyyy" and see if it works instead of MMMM?

Comment: Well the first one rungs fine on my computer. About the second one, because the exception is being thrown, hence `birth` is reinitialized to null

Comment: I would suggest changing the call for your `SimpleDateFormat`to this : `(SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, Locale.US)`. That's explained [here by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html). Note that the constructor you use might not support all `Locale`.

Comment: @Jatin You're incorrect about "reinitializing" `birth`. Java doesn't arbitrarily rewrite existing variables because an exception happens somewhere.

Comment: Code in your above two example is almost same. Your Date does not seem to be null anywhere. Check if "birthcal" is null. Can not see where it is declared/initialized in your code.

Comment: At what line was the NullPointerException thrown?

Comment: @Jonathan Drapeau  Noted. Never knew that, it really helps :)
Chrylis, Andy, and Jimmy - The NullPointerError was thrown from the last line, turns out I forgot to initialise birthcal. Derp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guest that birthcal is a *java.util.Calendar* class's object reference (I can not see the definition of the reference).

If you change your last line `(birthcal.setTime(birth);)`

to:

```
Calendar birthcal = Calendar.getInstance();
birthcal.setTime(birth);
```

you won't have problems. If you leave

```
Calendar birthcal = null;
birthcal.setTime(birth);
```

You will get `java.lang.NullPointerException` because your code is trying to set 'birth' to a null.

Comment: It's trying to set a `null`'s time to a date.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now. You've been a great help.